# How to perform repair operations on ddrescued image?

Tags: ubuntu, data-recovery

How can I perform `Testdisk` or `fsck` on HDD image file created by `ddrescue`? Can I mount it and then will it be writable drive? First thing I would like to try is to recover superblock on image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For testdisk, you should be able to use "testdisk image.img" and it'll come up in your drive selection.

Google suggests that you should be able to run "fsck image.img" and have it work as well. Derived from http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-1285560.html

Comment: The changes will modify .img file or they will be only in memory(temporary)?

Comment: They would modify the .img file. What I did in my case was take the img and copy it to a second img, then ran rescue and tests against the second one, in case rescue attempts further mucked up the damaged filesystem. You can use md5 checksums to verify the copy and again to verify changes were made to the second image.